# -32767 Why is this function returned?

Tags: c

Ive looked everywhere for the answer to this question, why does -32767 or & 0x8000 return as Key down when using the function below

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(KeyCapture) == -32767) 
{
Printf(“KeyCapture”);
}
```

Literally cannot find this answer anywhere, i need to understand how this function works! and why that number or hex value!

Comment: I think you need to try to ask the question better. I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: You did not look everywhere for the answer. It's the first google search result for `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace erm, well i think the first thing i did was check MSDN.com and google. Please link me to where you've found an explanation of why -32767 tells GetAsynKeyState that the key is down? instead of giving smug remarks

Comment: I'm really not trying to be smug or snarky. The MSDN page explicitly states the meaning of the most significant and least significant bits of the return value. dan04 links to the page in his answer below. Note: I'm also not a downvoter so you can't accuse me of that either :)

Comment: @Blastfurnace anywhere i can get a deeper explanation of these most and least significant bits? and why 0x8000 is one? or is that just a general rule

Comment: Hi, I just added a link in a comment for you below. Cheers!

Comment: It's a f***** short int. If it's negative, the bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

> If the most significant bit [0x8000] is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set [0x0001], the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

-32767 = 0x8001, so  both of the above bits are set.

Comment: Whoever coded it as `-32767` should be shot, or at least banned from all programming activity. Also, the doc says setting the low bit isn't reliable, so this code is broken.

Comment: I checked MSDN's GetAsynKeyState function and couldn't find an answer anywhere.

@JimBalter, don't be keyboard warrior everyone has to start somewhere

Comment: @dan04 when you say most significant bit[0x8000] what do you mean?

Comment: @BenArmstrong: [Most significant bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) :)

Comment: Appreciate this help would give you guys reps if i was of any value haha

Comment: `-32767` is a negative number and `0x8001` is a positive number, they are not equal. (Try doing `if ( -32767 == 0x8001 )` if you don't believe). If `SHORT` is a 16-bit signed integral type, then `-32767` is correct. `0x8001` is out of range for this type, and assigning it would invoke implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: @BenArmstrong Sorry, mate, I thought you were showing someone else's code and wondering how it works -- I didn't realize you wrote it to illustrate the return value, which is cool.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I was being imprecise with the notation.  What I meant was that `(SHORT) 0x8001` is equal to -32767 on any system where `SHORT` is a 16-bit integer type and negative integers are stored in two's complement form, which AFAIK is valid for all hardware architectures on which Windows runs.